# Pandas: What are the cases when count returned by DataFrame describe is a floating point

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

When describing my Pandas dataframe: I get the following result:

```
           Mains_1_Power  Mains_2_Power
count      17.000000      17.000000
mean       57.063528     200.428607
std        67.605151      69.364919
min        11.015203     135.492259
25%        31.850638     161.546607
50%        35.871114     183.986024
75%        56.419915     210.772911
max       312.787603     446.077603
```

I do not understand the cases where count should be a float, do we have half records?
If the count is always an integer, is it just the representation, which is floating point?
It can be confusing to put up results where count is not an integer. Is there a workaround?

Comment: It returns a data frame with each column being of one single type, so they all should be float. I don't see why you would need a workaround. You can always cast to int if you want to...

Comment: Agreed. But looks weird if you show the results to someone without explaining about the same.

Comment: Yeah... Well, you can always present it in whatever format, right? Just print it out in a custom way rather than inbuilt dataframe print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count will always be an integer with type `float64` (rather than type `int`).

This is purely for presentation, because DataFrames columns must have the same type (or, at least, there are performance gains in them doing so over `object` type).