# Changing the dtype of a row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A new dataframe is returned when the `.describe()` method is called on a dataframe.  In my project, the values in the "counts" row display as floats, with many zeros, which is ugly.  A count should be an int, since it is literally a count of the number of values.

I'd like the counts row to display as ints, but I can't find a way to change the dtype of a specific row.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
df_stats = df.describe()
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: What are the cases when count returned by DataFrame describe is a floating point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621963/pandas-what-are-the-cases-when-count-returned-by-dataframe-describe-is-a-floati)

Answer (score 2):

Use `astype(object)`

```
df_stats.astype(object)

              0          1         2
count         5          5         5
mean   0.551652   0.577811  0.494294
std    0.229048   0.312622   0.28331
min    0.185523  0.0350725  0.136097
25%    0.542329   0.651676  0.275079
50%    0.544838   0.652151  0.538186
75%    0.706685   0.713614   0.74606
max    0.778883   0.836541   0.77605
```

Comment: @RRMC don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That simple:

```
df_stats.iloc[0].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df_stats.loc['count'].astype(int)
```